# about int [] array in java and token error

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ScoreIt2
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ScoreIt h= new ScoreIt();
        System.out.println(h.maxPoints([2, 2, 3, 5, 4 ]));
    }
}

public class ScoreIt 
{
    public int maxPoints(int[] toss) 
    {
    }
}
```

I am trying to call a function from another file, and I have this for my code, and when i try to compile it, it says there is an token error.

Comment: When asking questions it's best to include the exact error message you're given by the compiler, and to comment any line numbers they reference.

Answer (score 5):

change

```
System.out.println(h.maxPoints([2, 2, 3, 5, 4 ]));
```

to

```
System.out.println(h.maxPoints(new int[] {2, 2, 3, 5, 4 }));
```

that is valid syntax

Comment: @JigarJoshi Let the party begin.